# Find all holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that

$$\limsup_{z\rightarrow 0}\left|\frac{f(z)}{\sin z}\right|<\infty$$

and

$$\limsup_{z\rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{f(z)}{z}\right|<\infty$$

I don't have any idea how to solve this. Any tips?

Comment: How long have you been working in this problem? Do not give up quickly!

Comment: since yesterday. I figured out that $f(z)=az$ satisfy this but are those only solutions?

Answer (score 3):

From the first condition, $\dfrac{f(z)}{\sin z}$ has a removable singularity at $0$. Hence $f(z) = g(z)\sin z$ for some holomorphic function $g$, at least locally. In particular, $f(0) = 0$.

On the other hand, from the second assumption, $f$ has a pole of order at most $1$ at infinity. Hence $f$ has to be a polynomial of degree at most $1$.

Hence $f(z) = cz$ for some $c$.

Added more details, since apparantly someone thought it wasn't clear enough.